# Hibernation mode in Windows

Tags: operating-system, system-monitoring, system-restore

Is it possible to resume the current work session on a computer(Windows)  in another computer (Windows) by copying the hiberfil.sys file?

Answer (score 4):

No. Technical aspects aside, this would be a catastrophe security-wise.